# how to get a current session value using php?

Tags: php, captcha

i used captcha coding in my form.the following is the coding of captcha creation

```
<?php  
   session_start();  

    $string = '';  

   for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
     {  
       $string .= chr(rand(97, 122));  
     }  

  $_SESSION['rand_code'] = $string;  



  $dir = 'fonts/';  

  $image = imagecreatetruecolor(150,60) or die('Cannot Initialize new image ');  
  $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);  
  $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 200, 100, 90); 
  $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);  

  imagefilledrectangle($image,0,50,150,100,$black);  
  imagettftext ($image, 30, 0, 10, 40, $color, $dir."BauhausMedium.ttf", $_SESSION['rand_code']);  


  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");  
  imagejpeg($image);  

  imagedestroy($image);




?>
```

In other page i call this code using img tag.

but the problem is, In that  page i want captcha image in textbox.i used $_session['rand_code']; but i displays previous session value that is previous captcha image value.
i want current image value in that page?

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the captcha code *after* you load the form, because the image in the form actually triggers the captcha code.

You should only check the captcha after the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is to create the random code and save it in the session at the page that will have the img tag. And at the page that the image is created just read the session.